# Local Variable Naming Conventions in .NET

Tags: .net, naming-conventions

I know that the [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) really don't say anything about that, but I am just curious to know... When you declare a variable local to a given method, do you `PascalCase` or `camelCase` it?

Comment: +1. IMO the close vote is unjustified. If for nothing else, this question is valuable because it points out that Microsoft's Framework Design Guidelines don't deal with local variables -- I've never noticed that before. I can see the likely reason for that now: they're not publicly visible (for framework users) and therefore don't have to be "standardised". But to framework *developers*, a guideline for local variables might actually be helpful when it comes to code uniformity. That's why I find this an reasonable question.

Comment: Checkout resharper. It is excellent at recommending a consistent code style for this situation (default is the common camelCase). Once you get used to it you will realize visual studio is actually broken without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SyleCop has a rule for this: [SA1306: FieldNamesMustBeginWithLowerCaseLetter](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1306.html)

I beleive this applies to fields and variables.

Answer (score 8):

You'll see `camelCase` used more often.

But the most important thing is to use whatever convention you decide on consistently - it'll make your code much easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

I'd vote `camelCase` when it comes to local variables:

1. My understanding so far has been that `PascalCase` is generally used for publicly visible names, while `camelCase` is used for just about everything else. (I'm aware that this is a very broad generalization. Parameters, for example, are a notable exception to this rule.)
2. When thinking about local variables, I tend to throw them in the same pot as fields and parameters, and these are usually all `camedCased`.

Answer (score 2):

I love to use `PascalCase`. But actually it is up to you. Normally I will use longer name that is more descriptive of what the specific variable does. For example:

dim `HaveValueIndicator` as boolean = False

dim `CountingTheTotalEggs` as int32 = 0